# Check the number of row in SAS dataset

Tags: awk, sas, records

I am giving the below command to check the number of rows in SAS data set but it's outputting the 60 records  of dataset however the dataset have 247 records.

Is there is any other way to do in unix command?

UNIX command:

awk 'END {print NR}' /home/user/check.sas7bdat

Comment: `awk` commands are for text files, a SAS7BDAT file is not a text file at all.

Comment: Hi Reeza , Thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a SAS program to output the number of observations for you.  The structure of the sas7bdat file is complicated.

```
data _null_;
   file stdout;
   set "&sysparm" nobs=nobs;
   put "NOBS:" nobs;
   stop;
run;
```

I named this "test.sas"

This reads in the data set specified in a passed system parameter and outputs to STDOUT the number of observations.

I created a test data set in my home directory like:

```
libname d "~/";

data d.test;
do i=1 to 1000;
   output;
end;
run;
```

From the command line run

```
<path to sas>/sas test.sas -sysparm ~/test.sas7bdat
```

I get `NOBS:1000` back.

Comment: @MPUSA, you're welcome.  Please accept and upvote the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

What about just doing it in a SAS datastep? You can fetch the number of rows with the `NOBS` statement.

```
/* Test dataset */
data have;
    a = 1;output;
    a = 2;output;
    a = 3;output;
run;


data _null_;
    set have NOBS = size;
    call symput("size",strip(size));
run;

%put NOTE: Number of records: &size.;
```

> ```
> NOTE: Number of records: 3
> ```

Comment: Hi TherKel, Thank you for suggestion.